# Int.tryparse does not work correctly in If condition - any explanation?

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, tryparse

Here is my piece of code using the `Int32.TryParse` with if condition.(console application)

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the no of the person(value for n)");
string number = Console.ReadLine();            
Console.WriteLine("Enter the no of the bulb whose state you want to check(value for x)");
string bulbNumber = Console.ReadLine();           
if ((Int32.TryParse(number, out n)) || (Int32.TryParse(bulbNumber, out x)))
{
}
```

if we check the value for n in quickwatch, then it correctly captures the value you input , but if you check the value for x, it is surprisingly 0!!! - Any ideas how to overcome this? I wonder what is causing this anomaly.

Comment: Try parsing outside the if statement, just to solve your problem.

Comment: You have an `||` Or condition. it will be true when number is parsed and it will enter into the if body. use `&&` instead

Comment: As mentioned because of the || if the first part of the condition evaluates to true the second part of the statement will not be reached hence x stays as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course the value of x is 0, after parsing to n you already got a "true" in your or condition, so the second tryparse will never be executed. if you want to make sure both are parseable use an and condition:

```
if ((Int32.TryParse(number, out n)) && (Int32.TryParse(bulbNumber, out x)))
```

Comment: @KuruvillaPhilip, no problem. I would also look into other operators, they become very useful as you progress! :). You can use the links provided in my answer to find what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You should use && rather than ||, "||" is saying if one is true, which one is so it ignores the second. Using && both must be true.

```
if ((Int32.TryParse(number, out n)) && (Int32.TryParse(bulbNumber, out x)))
{
      //Go crazy
}
```

Your original code meant that it would do this:

First tryparse || Second tryparse

First completed > straight into if statement, ignores second as one has passed.

With the && it says both **MUST** be true.

For further information on this you can use MSDN to see examples of the differences in  the conditional statements:

[&& operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[|| operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6373h346%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)